# Stronger connection (thicker point) between two lines

Tags: ultimaker-cura, pla, adhesion

I've just bought my first 3D printer, and I've started playing with it. But apparently, I have the problem that the raft won't stick. I mean, it sticks, for iteration (layer) or two, and after that it just disconnects. This is what I've checked until now:

- Bed is leveled properly, including Z, tried different variation of offsets
- Temperature of both bed and nozzle are okay (70 and 210 °C, it is PLA filament)
- Received slightly better results with adhesive for 3D printers, but still not ideal

Now, I've came up to the idea: I would like to try to interconnect each line in one layer (iteration) with thicker dot of melted filament for better adhesion. Unfortunately, I don't know how to setup this parameter in slicing software (Cura). Does anyone eventually know where I can find this parameter in Cura? In addition, here it is the extract of the GCODE:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:8750
;Filament used: 3.97836m
;Layer height: 0.15
;MINX:45.401
;MINY:52.901
;MINZ:0.36
;MAXX:154.6
;MAXY:147.099
;MAXZ:31.035
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 5.2.1
M140 S45
M105
M190 S45
M104 S210
M105
M109 S210
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
G28 ;Home
G1 Z15.0 F6000 ;Move the platform down 15mm
;Prime the extruder
G92 E0
G1 F200 E3
G92 E0
G92 E0
G92 E0
G1 F1500 E-6.5
;LAYER_COUNT:199
;LAYER:-7
M107
G0 F7200 X49.177 Y57.705 Z0.36
;TYPE:SUPPORT-INTERFACE
G1 F1500 E0
G1 F1350 X48.447 Y58.574 E0.05124
G1 X47.809 Y59.466 E0.10075
G1 X47.23 Y60.43 E0.15151
G1 X46.778 Y61.31 E0.19618

...

;TIME_ELAPSED:8750.646320
G1 F1500 E835.92386
M140 S0
M104 S0
M140 S0
;Retract the filament
G92 E1
G1 E-1 F300
G28 X0 Y0
M84
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
M104 S0
;End of Gcode
;SETTING_3 {"global_quality": "[general]\\nversion = 4\\nname = Normal #2\\ndefi
;SETTING_3 nition = custom\\n\\n[metadata]\\ntype = quality_changes\\nquality_ty
;SETTING_3 pe = fast\\nsetting_version = 20\\n\\n[values]\\nadhesion_type = raft
;SETTING_3 \\nmaterial_bed_temperature = 45.0\\n\\n", "extruder_quality": ["[gen
;SETTING_3 eral]\\nversion = 4\\nname = Normal #2\\ndefinition = custom\\n\\n[me
;SETTING_3 tadata]\\ntype = quality_changes\\nquality_type = fast\\nsetting_vers
;SETTING_3 ion = 20\\nposition = 0\\n\\n[values]\\ncool_fan_enabled = False\\nin
;SETTING_3 fill_pattern = grid\\ninfill_sparse_density = 80\\nmaterial_print_tem
;SETTING_3 perature = 210.0\\nretraction_hop_enabled = True\\nspeed_print = 60.0
;SETTING_3 \\n\\n"]}
```

Comment: Is 70 Recommended for the bed? We used to print PLA with the bed at 40.

Comment: Yep, 60 to 70, according to the specification. :)

Comment: Which printer do you have? PLA should print very easily, 70 bed is quite hot, and generally PLA doesn't need a raft.

Comment: It is some Voxelab... You think I should try it with lower temperatures on bed? I will give it a go tomorrow on both 40 and 50 degrees, and will inform you about the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some "experimenting", I've managed to resolve the problem. There were several contributors to the problem I had:

- I had to replace the slicing software; My printer did not accept G-code from Cura perfectly, even after a detailed configuration of Cura, according to my printer specs. Instead, I've downloaded and used OEM slicing software (in this case Voxelab)
- Printing speed was too high; With printing speed reduced from 60 mm/s to 40 mm/s situation significantly improved. Apparently, the extruder could not keep up with filament delivery at higher speeds
- Increased PLA temperature to 230 °C.; This also partially resolved the filament distribution problem. Bed temperature remained at 60 °C, with quite good success (I've used adhesive as well)

Answer (score 1):

Your work-around is a description to resolve a problem without resolving the problem. A properly tuned 3D printer will place the first layer on the bed (without a raft!) in such a manner as to allow the entire print to be completed.

Consider to print a single layer rectangle created in any software with which you are comfortable. A rectangle of 100 mm square would be large enough for analysis. Also, edit your question to reflect the current layer thickness and speeds you are using.

The single layer should present uniform width as the filament is applied to the bed. Each adjacent "stripe" should have minimal overlap with the previously applied stripe. Too much overlap (excessive extrusion factor) will create bulges between stripes. Insufficient overlap will result in gaps.

This rectangle print will provide feedback for your bed leveling as well as the z-offset. Excessive z-offset will reduce the grip of the filament to the bed.

Using adhesive and having poor results leads me to suggest the first layer is at a too-high z-offset, but your test will provide a better answer.

Even though I've seen a few references to PLA not requiring drying, PLA and other filament types can have problems with bed adhesion if there is too much humidity absorbed into the filament. Consider to dry your spool for four to six hours to see if improvement will result.

Lastly, you should not need to use a raft, unless a specific aspect of your model requires it. I've seen rafts "required" in low quality, low cost, low performance 3D printers with poor bed planar characteristics. One will hope your printer is not in that category.

Comment: Thank you for extensive explanation/comment. I've tried variation of lower temperatures on bed (40-50) + few more calibrations of the bed (with accent on z-offset). It did not help. In addition, I've updated my question with part of the GCODE and settings that could eventually help to demistify the problem.